# демон и файл /etc/hosts

Tags: linux, bash, debian, daemon

На виртуалке (`kvm`) с `debian10` у меня крутится демон, который при старте (старте демона) коннектится к `ip` под именем `test` определенном в `/etc/hosts`. С помощью `systemctl enable` я добавил этот демон в список демонов, которые стартуют при старте системы, а в скрипте запуска указал зависимость от `network manager`. Проблема заключается в том, что когда я перезагружаю систему, то обнаруживаю, что демон не стартовал (провалился), при этом когда я его рестартую (без перезагрузки) то он запускается и все работает. Обнаружил, что если нужный `ip` для демона определить не через имя (`test`) а захардкодить (всмысле записать в виде `127.0.0.1` к примеру), то проблемы не возникает. Но такой вариант меня не устраивает, поэтому я нашел еще одно решение: в конфигурационный скрипт демона добвить строку

```
ExecStartPre=sleep 15
```

В результате после перезагрузки демон стартует не сразу, а только через 15 секунд.

Почему так происходит? Когда в системе становятся доступны алиасы прописанные в `/etc/hosts`?

PS Для справки: с этой проблемой я столкнулся при использовании демонов `nginx` и `mongo`

Comment: Может стоит не хардкорить ожидание в 15 секунд, а подождать пока поднимется сеть? `After=network.target`

Comment: @donRumata я в вопросе написал, что уже есть зависимость от network manager - читайте вниманительнее

Comment: ну, вообще-то программа network-manager и цель network — вещи немного разные. попробовать добавить ещё одну зависимость не так уж и сложно.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin согласен, что не сложно, но вот только никакого результата это все равно не дает

Comment: а в nsswitch.conf и resolv.conf что написанно? попробуйте через ExecStartPre= подглядеть что там

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, как вариант оптимизации вашего текущего решения: вместо `sleep 15` укажите `while ! ping -w 1 -c 1 test >/dev/null; do sleep 1; done`. Т.е. вместо приостановки запуска сервиса на фиксированные 15сек - в цикле пингуем одним пакетом, с ожиданием ответа в течении 1 сек, если ответ не получен, то приостанавливается на  1сек и повторям пинг. И так пока ответ не будет получен.  Это, имхо, сократит время запуска вашего сервиса.

Comment: @Jigius да, действительно хороший вариант

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте активировать во время загрузки, сервис `systemd-networkd-wait-online`:

`systemctl enable systemd-networkd-wait-online.service`

В ваш Unit добавьте строки:

```
[Unit]
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target network-online.target
...
```

Это включит ожидание для сервиса `systemd-networkd` успешного конфигурирования всех интефейсов(указанных в systemd-networkd.service) и наступления момента, когда хотя-бы один из них перешел в рабочее состояние.

Comment: Помимо добавления сервиса в автозапуск, ещё нужно что-либо? Если нет, то этот способ не работает

Comment: У вас ip-адрес на интерфейсе, через который рабочий доступ к ресурсам сети требуется, во время загрузки,  как назначается? статик? dhcp?

Comment: дополнил свой ответ

Comment: адрес статический, а необходимые строки уже добавлены в конфиг сервиса, но, к сожалению, он все также отказывается запускаться при перезагрузке